# Android app doesn't display in portrait mode when displayed through HDMI

Tags: android, android-manifest, hdmi

Is it possible to set an app so that it runs in portrait mode when plugged into an HDMI display?

I've placed android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"         android:screenOrientation="portrait" in each activity but these seem to be ignored when the device is displayed through HDMI.

Comment: Why not allow users to use your app both portrait and landscape?